# How to select the build while creating a new app version on App Store Connect using Fastlane

Tags: ios, app-store, fastlane

I am using Fastlane commands to upload the .ipa file to Apple Store Testflight and to submit the build for approval.

Once the version is on Testflight I have an issue promoting it to the Production track.

I am using the following command to create a new version.

fastlane deliver --force --precheck_include_in_app_purchases false --api_key_path /Users/runner/work/_temp/api_key***.json -a my.bundle.id --skip_binary_upload true -j ios --skip_metadata true --skip_screenshots true --automatic_release false --ipa /Users/runner/work/r1/a/_iOS-App-PROD/drop/bundle.ipa --verbose

It works fine. The version is created but the build is not selected as in the picture below. I need to select the build manually on App Store Connect.

[Version created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwPjk.png)

[Selecting build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PveBS.png)